# Error in QGIS The following layers were not correctly generated

Tags: qgis

I new in qgis and i have error when trying to polygonize raster layer in vector. I dont understand - why its not working.
Image from photoshop in 2 colors - black and transparent.
Can somebody help me?
Thx!

[image]

```
QGIS version: 3.8.2-Zanzibar
QGIS code revision: 4470baa1a3
Qt version: 5.11.2
GDAL version: 2.4.1
GEOS version: 3.7.2-CAPI-1.11.0 b55d2125
PROJ version: Rel. 5.2.0, September 15th, 2018
Processing algorithm…
Algorithm 'Polygonize (raster to vector)' starting…
Input parameters:
{ 'BAND' : 1, 'EIGHT_CONNECTEDNESS' : False, 'FIELD' : 'DN', 'INPUT' : 'C:/Users/Ya/Desktop/youdrive_countur_modified.tif', 'OUTPUT' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT' }

GDAL command:
python3 -m gdal_polygonize C:/Users/Ya/Desktop/youdrive_countur_modified.tif C:/Users/Ya/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_10b1eb77e9d647d793fbad6baec49774/30543f2183314e709d1b01c30ffa56ab/OUTPUT.shp -b 1 -f "ESRI Shapefile" OUTPUT DN
GDAL command output:
0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...Creating output C:/Users/Ya/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_10b1eb77e9d647d793fbad6baec49774/30543f2183314e709d1b01c30ffa56ab/OUTPUT.shp of format ESRI Shapefile.

100 - done.

Execution completed in 6.84 seconds
Results:
{'OUTPUT': 'C:/Users/Ya/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_10b1eb77e9d647d793fbad6baec49774/30543f2183314e709d1b01c30ffa56ab/OUTPUT.shp'}

Loading resulting layers
The following layers were not correctly generated.<ul><li>C:/Users/Ya/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_10b1eb77e9d647d793fbad6baec49774/30543f2183314e709d1b01c30ffa56ab/OUTPUT.shp</li></ul>You can check the 'Log Messages Panel' in QGIS main window to find more information about the execution of the algorithm.
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why, but after reinstall qgis all works fine. Before i used qgis 3.8. Now install 3.4 and all fine. System Win 10.
...